# Django render_to _response to render?

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django. reading tutorial to create blog (http://www.djangorocks.com). They are using render_to _response() to create views. But I want to convert it into render().

How this can be done ?

```
from djangorocks.blog.models import Blog, Category
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'posts': Blog.objects.all()[:5]
    })

def view_post(request, slug):   
    return render_to_response('view_post.html', {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
    })

def view_category(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('view_category.html', {
        'category': category,
        'posts': Blog.objects.filter(category=category)[:5]
    })
```

Comment: OK, so what's stopping you? The only difference is that render takes the request as the first parameter, as clearly described in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). What's the problem?

Comment: Aactully I am new to Django and somewhere i read that creating views using render_to _response() and render() is little bit different. So I confused. BTW Thanks. I will try @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call:

`render_to_response(template_name, context)`

Where `context` is `dict` containing all the data you want to send to template, and `template_name` is the link to template (eg. `view_category.html` in your code)

In `render` function becomes this:

`render(request, template_name, context)`

where `request` is the argument you get in view function.